# Conflicting types for C method using jni?

Tags: c, function, java-native-interface

I get this error:

```
conflicting types for ‘Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler’
Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler() {
^
In file included from SharedTable.c:5:0:
model_JNIResultSet.h:15:32: note: previous declaration of ‘Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler’ was here
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler
                            ^
```

My code in C looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "model_JNIResultSet.h"

struct Spieler {
  char  vorname[50];
  char  nachname[50];
  int   trikotnummer;
  struct Spieler *next;
}; 

struct Spieler *head = NULL;
struct Spieler *current = NULL;



JNIEXPORT struct Spieler* JNICALL
Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler() {
int c;
int count = 0;
FILE *file;
char myStrings[MAXCHARS];

file = fopen("Spieler.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        myStrings[count] = c;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

int len = strlen(myStrings);
int j = 0;
int attributeCount = 1;
char newArray[MAXCHARS];

for (c = 0; c < len - 1; c++) {
    if (myStrings[c] != '\n') {
        newArray[j] = myStrings[c];
        j++;
    } else {
        j = 0;
        if (attributeCount == 4) {
            attributeCount = 1;
        }
        //newArray[strlen(newArray)+1] = '\0';
        insertFirst(newArray, attributeCount);
        attributeCount++;
        memset(newArray, 0, sizeof(newArray));
    }
}

// reverse the data
reverse(&head);

return head;
}
```

What could be the error here? I've absolutely no idea and I've also searched for a long time but I don't know how to fix it.
What could be the `previous declaration` in the .h file?
Here is the .h file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class model_JNIResultSet */

#ifndef _Included_model_JNIResultSet
#define _Included_model_JNIResultSet
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
* Class:     model_JNIResultSet
* Method:    getSpieler
* Signature: ()[Lmodel/Spieler;
*/
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler
(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you notice in your declaration (.h) file, your signature is

`JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler
(JNIEnv *, jobject);`
Notice the *`jobjectArray`* is your return type.

In your implementation, you are replacing the return type with `struct Spieler *`. You cannot mismatch types in this way for valid C.

Finally, you are going to run into a problem, because `jobjectArray` means that it must be a Java Array type (primitive Java Array).

You cannot return native structures straight to the JVM like this, assuming that is your intent.

To make this work correctly, based on your JNI Signature of `()[Lmodel/Spieler`, you will need to create an array (using JNIEnv's `NewObjectArray` method), and then instantiate a Java `model.Spieler` object, putting it in that array, and returning it. You will have to copy your C struct data into the Java object.

Comment: So returning `jlong` is the best way to return my linked list?

Comment: No sorry, I updated my comment, realizing your intent is to return an array of model.Spieler objects. Using the pointer from the Java side will be an exercise in frustration anyway.